# Как лучше реализовать хранение подгружаемых из бд для пользователя данных в Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, flask

Я новичок в WEB. Стала задача написать сайт в Flask. Не пойму, как лучше реализовать вывод данных на страницу пользователя из БД. Дилемма: при каждом обновлении запрашивать инфу из БД и выводить, или как-то можно всё  закэшировать после первого обращения. При каждом обновлении страницы будет обращении к БД и вдруг этим начнут флудить ?

У меня есть идея при помощи js выводить данные с определённой задержкой, с помощью ajax по таймеру. И пользователю показать служебный прогресс-бар загрузки данных. Это будет происходить после перехода на страницу, где эти данные и будут показаны. Мысль правильная?

Я не прошу код, а лишь ценный совет бывалых. Заранее спасибо.

Как лучше быть ?

Comment: Можно закэшировать ответ на сервере и по запросу пользователя отдавать отает, ращ в некоторое время, обновляя кэш(допустимо для относительно статических данных в бд). Если данные в бд часто меняются, то в кэше нет никакого смысла.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Будут выводиться, например, логи и они как раз часто дополняются по мере активности пользователя. Получается смысла нет городить. А как предотвратить флуд загрузки многократной загрузки страницы, если это возможно ?

Comment: Что такое - флуд загрузки?

Comment: Вы бы не использовали слова, которые не знаете. "дилемма", например. и вообще, знание грамматики никогда не повредит.

Comment: А вы сюда приходите грамматике поучить или помогать людям, отвечая на вопросы ? РУ ветка от западной и отличается тем, что тут не помогут, а попробуют принизить за любую ошибку в слове или коде. Вы наверное ошиблись тематикой своей деятельности. Вам следует идти преподавать русский язык, если так глаз коробит.

Comment: Что такое - флуд загрузки? – 
SwaD
 Я имел ввиду если пользователь каким либо способом будет вызывать старницу, например, 50 раз в секкунду каким нибудь флудером, тем самым окажет значительную нагрузку на ресурсы машины. Возможно такое  ?

Comment: Возможно, решением будет некоторые данные пользователя записать в куки или сессии. И их выводить. А так же, намного легче использовать модуль Flask-login. При авторизации пользователя на сайте, у него создаётся специальный объект current_user. При авторизации, объект создаётся 1 раз, а данные из него вызывать можно многократно. При перезагрузке, данные не подтягиваются заново из БД, тк они там вроде в сессиях хранятся.

Comment: Большое спасибо), ценная подсказка.